# AnyLogic - time in stock (variable)

Tags: variables, time, anylogic, stock

I have a problem with time measuring within a variable. I have a stock (variable) that is filled up at different times with different amounts. I would like to measure how long every product is in stock so that I can calculate the stock costs. Do you maybe have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a System-Dynamics stock, you can't. As soon as something enters an SD stock, it is "lost in the liquid", i.e. it is not really an agent/object anymore that you can track. You do not have individual "products" anymore.

There is also no way to keep track of individual products when they leave.

Imagine an SD stock like a glass of water. Once you add a drop of water, it is impossible to trace it. When you let a drop of water out, it is impossible to say which initial drop it was.

So you would need to switch to a non-SD approach to be able to do this. Luckily, you can convert any SD model to an AB model, see the example models on SIR: there is the standard SD model and a converted AB model.